# Is this 64-bit Encoded?

Tags: c#, encryption

All of the passwords in our User DB look like this where we have == at the end:

91F2FSEYrFOcabeHK/UfNw==

So how can I tell if this is 64-bit encoded?   It has to be because I can decode using a decode 64-bit routine I have.

I am trying now to figure out how to decode a literal string to 64-bit..back to the xxxxxxxx== and here is my code:

```
string passwordToEncrypt = "test";
byte[] passwordToBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordToEncrypt);
result = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordToBytes);
```

Updated:

I need the text test to come out in Base64 with the == at the end.

Comment: what exactly is the question/problem ?

Comment: my last sentence "I am trying now to figure out how to decode a literal string to 64-bit..back to the xxxxxxxx== and here is my code:"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 describes how padding is determined. assuming i understand your question and your code converts back to Base64 but without the '='s at the end, there should be 0, 1, or 2 '='s at the end of the encoded string, and that should be computable i believe based on the number of chars in the unencoded value % 3. (although i would verify this to your satisfaction)

Comment: see this [Encoding Strings to Base64 in C#](http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/)

Comment: we have a method that decrypts passwords like 91F2FSEYrFOcabeHK/UfNw==..with teh == at the end

Comment: Good grief, converting to Base 64 is not encryption. I really hope you're not responsible for security on this DB.

Comment: ok encoding, I'm keeping with the stupid name of the tool that exists that I did not code

Comment: OK, fair enough, many people do seem to get encryption and encoding confused. You've got your answer, Base 64 does not **require** == at the end, so if that is what you have then either it's not Base 64 or the unencoded password is always some fixed length. Whether there is == on the end on a Base 64 encoded string depends strictly on the length of original string. But they do look like Base 64 strings.

Comment: Wow, I'm not self proclaiming anything.

Comment: Well I know we're decoding 64-bit because we have a method doing so when needed.  Just trying to figure out how to get it to that same format and I don't have access to the assembly where we're calling our decode class to try to see if that can help me determine what format we're actually encoding to 64-bit by

Comment: Just to get the terms straight: base64 is not the same as 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in there - so the above code does not compile, try

```
        string passwordToEncrypte = "test";
        byte[] passwordToBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordToEncrypte);
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordToBytes);
```

`result` contains now a "Base64"-encoded password and end with "=="...

BUT the above code works only for passwords containing `ASCII`... if you want it to work with `UTF8` passwords then change it to :

```
        string passwordToEncrypte = "test";
        byte[] passwordToBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(passwordToEncrypte);
        string result = Convert.ToBase64String(passwordToBytes);
```

to go back from Base64 to the original you need to do:

```
        string Original = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (Convert.FromBase64String(result));
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hf4sb8.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx

Comment: System.Text.UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordToEncrypt);

Answer (score 0):

Base64 encoded string doesn't always end with a =, it will only end with one or two = if they are required to pad the string out to the proper length.For more details checkout following link

[Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29)

Comment: Looks like I might need UTF8Encoding

Comment: then how come all our passwords end with == in our huge User table?  I mean there has to be some right way to get this encoded to that?

Comment: If they are all the same length then they will have the same number of '=' at the end.  What you may have is the Base64 representation of a fixed length hash of the password (plus possibly a salt).  With a hash, all passwords will end up the same length.